# How to get refresh signal at the end of scrolling page using GridView

Tags: qt, qml

Hi how to use `VisibilityRefreshHandler` (**Felgo lib**) with `GridView` .As i understood it is related to `ListView` , so what is equivalent of `VisibilityRefreshHandler` for `GridView`. What i want is to get for example `refresh signal` to know when user scrolled to the end of page and load new piece of date.

Comment: What is `VisibilityRefreshHandler`? Please clarify the question. As for the end page detection, I would use [movementEnded()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#movementEnded-signal) signal and then you just cant play with contentY/contentHeight to check if you get to the end of page.

Comment: @folibis `VisibilityRefreshHandler` This item is a convenience item that can be added as the header or footer of an `AppListView`.

As soon as the item gets visible within the `AppListView` the refresh signal is emitted. `AppListView {
   footer: VisibilityRefreshHandler {
     onRefresh: twitterCient.loadNextTweets()
   }
 }` Thanks for response i will try your suggestion

Comment: `VisibilityRefreshHandler` and `AppListView`, both of these components are non -standard, you should point this out, provide link to the library etc. Otherwise people won't understand your question

Comment: @folibis yes sure sory. Here Link for `VisibilityRefreshHandler  `https://felgo.com/doc/felgo-visibilityrefreshhandler/ and for `AppListView` https://felgo.com/doc/felgo-applistview/    it is Felgo library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks folibis for suggestion to use `movementEnded()` signal. I also found `atYEnd`
property. This property is true if the flickable view is positioned at the end exactly what i need. SO here is my code how i managed it

```
GridView
{
    onMovementEnded:
    {

        if(atYEnd )
        {
           logic.getImages()
        }
    }
 }
```